# How do I make my boolean return the value true? Because it keeps returning false

Tags: java, boolean

I'm using the three layers architecture. In servlet, before I get to the methods, I have to check whether my boolean is true or false in my DAO layer. If false, it will go to the first method, if true, it will go to the second method.

I don't know what went wrong but it keeps returning the false one. So I'm stuck with one method even though I want another method. Below is my DAO layer:

```
public static RPHS getRph(RPHS rph)  {
        rph_id = rph.getRph_id();

        String searchQuery = "select * from rphs where rph_id='" + rph_id + "'";

        try {
            currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = currentCon.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(searchQuery);
            boolean more = rs.next();

            // if rph exists set the isValid variable to true
            if (more) {
                int rph_id = rs.getInt("rph_id");
                rph.setRph_id(rph_id);
                rph.setValid(true);
            }

            else if (!more) {
                rph.setValid(false);
            }

        }
}
```

How do I make it return the value true? Is something wrong with my query?

Comment: Your query is not returning any rows; are you sure that rph_id exists in the database? If so, are you sure it's a char type?

Comment: @Lino `rph` is passed by (value) reference.

Comment: I'm sorry but  what do you guys mean by not returning any rows/ return nothing? Is it the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement`, also use dynamic query, like..

```
String searchQuery = "select * from rphs where rph_id=?";
```

and pass value to ? mark.

```
Ex. stmt.setInt(1,101);
```

after taking result in ResultSet use-

```
if (rs.next())
{
   int rph_id = rs.getInt("rph_id");
   rph.setRph_id(rph_id);
   rph.setValid(true);
}else {
        rph.setValid(false);
}
```

Comment: is this what I'm supposed to do? @Sudarshan  `public static RPHS getRph(RPHS rph) {

  try {
   currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
   ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("select * from rphs where rph_id=?");

   ps.setInt(1, rph_id);
   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


   if (rs.next()) {
    rs.getInt("rph_id");
    rph.setRph_id(rph_id);
    rph.setValid(true);
   }

   else  {
    rph.setValid(false);
   }
  }`